# Rails partial: using content_for to append javascript include tags only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a partial that requires some related script, so I want to append those javascript include tags to the header whenever the partial is used. So I did:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/tricky_js.js.coffee
alert "I've been required!!"

# app/views/layouts/application.slim
head
  # stuff...
  = yield :head

body
  = yield

# app/views/shared/_tricky_partial.slim
content_for :head do
  = javascript_include_tag :tricky_js

p Bleh

# app/views/shared/unrelated_view.slim
= render 'shared/tricky_partial'
= render 'shared/tricky_partial'
= render 'shared/tricky_partial'
```

Which of course causes the javascript tag to be appended 3 times and therefore to run `alert("I've been required!!")` 3 times. **How to append the script only once?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem came to me, so I decided to share the solution here. It's not a problem of high complexity but may spare you the half an hour it took me...:

```
- unless content_for? :tricky_partial_assets
  - content_for :tricky_partial_assets do
    = stylesheet_link_tag :columns
    = stylesheet_link_tag :feedback_table
    /* v here is (almost) all the JS powering this partial */
    = javascript_include_tag :feedback_table
    = javascript_include_tag :wish_list_items

/* Append only once */
- unless content_for? :tricky_partial_assets_provided
  - content_for :head, content_for(:tricky_partial_assets)
  - content_for :tricky_partial_assets_provided, true
```